# How do you check if an arithmetic operation will overflow?

Tags: c, rust, integer, integer-overflow

I am coming from looking at Rust and [How do I detect unsigned integer multiply overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-do-i-detect-unsigned-integer-multiply-overflow) where in Rust they have `checked_add`, which is implemented like this:

```
pub const fn checked_add(self, rhs: Self) -> Option<Self> {
  let (a, b) = self.overflowing_add(rhs);
  if unlikely!(b) {None} else {Some(a)}
}

pub const fn overflowing_add(self, rhs: Self) -> (Self, bool) {
  let (a, b) = intrinsics::add_with_overflow(self as $ActualT, rhs as $ActualT);
  (a as Self, b)
}

// can't find where this is implemented...
#[rustc_const_stable(feature = "const_int_overflow", since = "1.40.0")]
pub fn add_with_overflow<T: Copy>(x: T, y: T) -> (T, bool);
```

If you try adding two `u8` large integers, compiler doesn't let you:

```
fn main() {
  let a: u8 = 255;
  let b: u8 = 255;
  let c = a + b;
  // ^^^^^ attempt to compute `u8::MAX + u8::MAX`, which would overflow
}
```

How is this done in C? How can I simulate this sort of thing in JavaScript?

For example, in JavaScript. I guess in JavaScript you would check if it hits `Infinity`, as in `Number.MAX_VALUE * 2 == Infinity`. But in the case of Rust, how can I simulate this (or in C), using a specific low-level uint data type? (Without resorting to the `checked_add` helper methods which already solve it). Basically I am wondering how you can tell if it will overflow if the datatypes don't allow you to overflow.

I am working on building a programming language so would like to know how this is implemented.

Specifically right now what I am trying to do is, if you have a function called `get_next_power_of_2(u8)`, it should return a u8 if it fits, otherwise a u16. But not a u16 in all cases. So I am wondering how to first check that it is going to overflow, and if it does, cast to a higher int.

Comment: How are you building a programming language? Why does JavaScript matter? Is your programming language an interpreter or are you trying to compile to a native binary using something like LLVM?

Comment: It is unfortunately rather awkward to do correctly in standard C; you have to do things like `if (b > (255 - a))`.  If using gcc or a compatible compiler, they provide [overflow-checking builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html#Integer-Overflow-Builtins) as an extension.

Comment: At the lowest level of assembly, it's actually pretty easy because a typical CPU would have an overflow flag which is set automatically by arithmetic instructions. Then you can use this flag for a conditional branch, etc.  Unfortunately higher-level languages don't tend to expose this feature very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is this done in C?

When wider math is available, code could use that.

```
int a,b;
...
int_twice_as_wide product = (int_twice_as_wide) a * b;
if (product < INT_MIN || product > INT_MAX) Handle_Overflow();
```

With *signed* integer math, overflow is *undefined behavior* (UB), so when wider math not readily available, code could perform various pre-tests for `+ - * /` as done [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/93699/29485).

For *unsigned math*, overflow "wraps around" ( a module `UINT_MAX + 1`).  It is easy for `+ -` (below).  Division only need to watch for `/ 0`.

```
unsigned a,b;
...
unsigned sum = a + b;
if (sum < a) Handle_Overflow();
```

The *unsigned* `*` is much like the above referenced *signed* `*` code with fewer tests.

```
bool is_undefined_umult1(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
  if (b > 0) {
    return a > UINT_MAX / b; 
  }
  return false;
}
```

---

> it should return a u8 if it fits, otherwise a u16. But not a u16 in all cases.

C functions do not return different types depending upon value.  Instead consider:

```
uint16_t unt8_mul(unt8_t a, unt8_t b) {
  return (uint16_t) a * b;
}
```

For u8 * u8, avoid `a * b` as on 16-bit systems the multiplication is *signed*, the product may overflow and incur UB.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the sizes of the variables, you also know the maximum & minimum values they can store.
In C, you would check if the inverse operation is valid, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    // max value a 4-byte unsigned int can store is 0xFFFFFFFF
    unsigned int UINT32_MAX = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    // var_1 + var_2 would overflow, 
    // as an unsigned int can't hold 0x100000028 (0xFFFFFFFE + 0x2A)
    unsigned int var_1 = 0xFFFFFFFE;
    unsigned int var_2 = 0x2A;

    // check the inverse operation, which can be stored in memory
    // var_1 + var_2 > UINT32_MAX --> UINT32_MAX - var_2 < var_1
    if (UINT32_MAX - var_2 < var_1) {
        printf("Overflow\n");
    } else {
        printf("No overflow\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```